# Why does ("00e0" == "00e1") evaluate as true?

Tags: php

In PHP, why do the first two of the following statement evaluate true?

```
<?php
    if("00e0" == "00e1") {
        echo 'matches (a)';
    } else {
        echo 'failed (a)';
    }

    if("00e1" == "00e9") {
        echo 'matches (b)';
    } else {
        echo 'failed (b)';
    }

    if("00e2" == "00ea") {
        echo 'matches (c)';
    } else { 
        echo 'failed (c)';
    }
?>
```

If run this will return the following:

```
matches (a)
matches (b)
failed (c)
```

Any string between "00e0", "00e1", "00e2" .. "00e9"  will give true if compared with another "00e(0-9)" string.

Comment: Your terminology is off. There are no "returns" here. You are talking about _evaluation_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the strings that are valid floating point values are being interpreted as such.

For example, `00e0` is equivalent to `0 x 100` and `00e9` is equivalent to `0 x 109`, both of which are zero, and hence equal to each other.

However, since `00ea` is *not* a valid floating point number, it is being treated differently.

You can see a similar effect with:

```
echo "01e2" - "01e1";
```

which outputs `90` because it's the same as `1 x 102 - 1 x 101`, or `100 - 10`.

This is supported by the [PHP doco](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (my italics):

> If you compare a number with a string *or the comparison involves numerical strings,* then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

That paragraph links to [another page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) which explains the rules behind conversion, should it happen:

> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases *it will be evaluated as a float.*

If you want to *avoid* this behaviour, there's a note in that first link which states you should use `===` instead:

> The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Comment: Yet another reason PHP is terrible. Two obviously different strings are equal.

Comment: @Lego, I'm no fan of PHP but the language _has_ a way to avoid this, as per my update, something PHP aficionados would no doubt know. So it's no real different in concept to the incorrect `if (str == "another string")` in C that you'll often find beginners using.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr if you want to compare strings are equal you obviously  use === not ==.

Comment: Actually, the part up to the `e` is interpreted as octal notation and 0^x with x ≥ 0 is always 0.

Comment: @Gumbo, the bit about `0^x` is misleading - it's actually `0 * 10^x`, though still zero by virtue of the fact you're multiplying by zero. But I don't think it _is_ octal, the statement `echo "010e0" - 0;` gives you ten rather than eight. It also states it uses `strtod` under the covers and that doesn't handle octal.