# Why are these strings equal?

Tags: php

I'm comparing two strings that are identical except for the 5th character. PHP seems to think that they are the same when loosely compared and not the same when strictly compared (even though they are both strings, which means their types match). Am I going out of my mind, or is there a logical explanation for this?

```
[21:39 ~]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump('29273E-1443035285' == '29274E-1443035285');
bool(true)
php > var_dump('29273E-1443035285' === '29274E-1443035285');
bool(false)
php > %
[21:40 ~]$ php --version
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2016 11:50:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var_dump('29273E-1443035285' == '29274E-1443035285');
> ```

Those strings look like floats, so the comparison is performed in a numerical context and they're converted to doubles. Because they're so tiny, they both get interpreted as `double(0)`. That's why they `==` each other.

`===` tests them as strings, and since they're not the same string, the test returns `false`.

Comment: This makes sense. So it is interpreting them as floats because it thinks that "E" means exponent and -1443035285 is the exponent? That would explain why it occurs with this particular string but not most other ids I've processed.

Comment: Yup, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that PHP is evaluating those first set of figures as floating points and they are maxing out or equaling 0 (No good at math so I'm not sure what they would equal.).

The second version is testing them as strings.

See this thread for more information.
[Why does ("00e0" == "00e1") evaluate as true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159465/why-does-00e0-00e1-evaluate-as-true)

Comment: I gave a very small summary of the answer right below the link.

Comment: Whoops, still fairly new to commenting on stackoverflow so was trying to work out what I did wrong. Thanks. I'll update my answer.